# agrupar elementos en xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

Necesita ayuda con esto....
Tengo el siguiente xml, y necesito que se agrupe por editorial:

```
<biblioteca>
<libro>
    <titulo idioma="es">La vida está en otra parte</titulo>
    <autor>Milan Kundera</autor>
    <fechaPublicacion anyo="1973"/>
    <editorial>McGraw Hill</editorial>
</libro>
<libro>
    <titulo idioma="es">Pantaleón y las visitadoras</titulo>
    <autor>Mario Vargas Llosa</autor>
    <fechaPublicacion anyo="1973"/>
    <editorial>McGraw Hill</editorial>
</libro>
<libro>
    <titulo idioma="es">Conversación en la catedral</titulo>
    <autor>Mario Vargas Llosa</autor>
    <fechaPublicacion anyo="1969"/>
    <editorial>Santillana</editorial>
</libro>
<libro>
    <titulo idioma="en">Complete Stories and Poems of Edgar Allan Poe</titulo>
    <autor>Edgar Allan Poe</autor>
    <fechaPublicacion anyo="1890"/>
    <editorial>Santillana</editorial>
</libro>
<libro>
    <titulo idioma="fr">Les Miserables</titulo>
    <autor>Victor Hugo</autor>
    <fechaPublicacion anyo="1862"/>
    <editorial>Planeta</editorial>
</libro>
```

He probado con esto, pero me da error, y no se ya por donde mirar:

```
<p>c. Listado ordenado de libros, agrupados por editorial.</p>
            <ol>
                <xsl:for-each-group select="biblioteca/libro/editorial" group-by="text()">
                    <li>

                        <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>

                    </li>
                </xsl:for-each-group>
            </ol>
```

La salida tendría que ser la siguiente:
editorial: títulos
editorial: títulos
editorial: títulos

Ya que editoriales solo hay tres, alguna idea?

Muchas gracias por todo!

Comment: ¿Qué software utilizas para XSLT, qué error exactamente te ha dado? ¿Quieres agrupar los libros por editorial? En este caso, parece que cambiar `xsl:for-each-group select="biblioteca/libro/editorial" group-by="text()"` a `xsl:for-each-group select="biblioteca/libro" group-by="editorial"` debería ser el primer paso para resolverlo, entonces en lugar de `<xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>` utililza `<xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key(), ':', current-group()/titulo"/>`.

Answer (score 0):

Para agrupar los elementos "libro" por el elemento "editorial" utiliza `<xsl:for-each-group select="biblioteca/libro" group-by="editorial">` en lugar de `<xsl:for-each-group select="biblioteca/libro/editorial" group-by="text()">`.

Para presentar los títulos de cada grupo, cambia `<xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>` a `xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>` utililza `<xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key(), ':', current-group()/titulo"/>` o tal vez mejor `<xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key(), ':'"/><xsl:value-of select="current-group()/titulo" separator=", "/>`.

```
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>.NET XSLT Fiddle Example</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <p>c. Listado ordenado de libros, agrupados por editorial.</p>
            <ol>
                <xsl:for-each-group select="biblioteca/libro" group-by="editorial">
                    <li>

                        <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key(), ':'"/>
                        <xsl:value-of select="current-group()/titulo" separator=", "/>

                    </li>
                </xsl:for-each-group>
            </ol>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
```

Ejemplo en línea: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94rmq6M/1